# R split call to funciton over several lines

Tags: r, coding-style

I wonder if there is a way to split a call to a function in R over several lines, other then using commas or '+' which is not always applicable.
I am basically looking like Python's '\' escape.

For example, I want to display this line:

```
PromoterIslands$illumina_probes[bins_with_probes]-tapply(CGIP_to_Probe$subjectHits,CGIP_to_Probe$subjectHits,function(x) length(x))
```

as:

```
PromoterIslands$illumina_probes[bins_with_probes]
<-tapply(CGIP_to_Probe$subjectHits,CGIP_to_Probe$subjectHits,
function(x) length(x))]
```

Is there any way to do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about source (as opposed to desiring to get something to print a particular way), you can break R code in any place that doesn't produce a syntactically complete statement.  There is no special character that tells R that the statement isn't complete.  In your case, one option is:

```
PromoterIslands$illumina_probes[bins_with_probes] <- 
  tapply(
    CGIP_to_Probe$subjectHits,
    CGIP_to_Probe$subjectHits,
    function(x) length(x)
  )
```

You have to leave the `<-` at the end of the first line, otherwise `PromoterIslands$illumina_probes[bins_with_probes]` is a syntactically complete statement that would get evaluated.  Similarly, on the next line, you have to leave the `(` on the same line as `tapply` otherwise `tapply` is a syntactically complete statement (returns the contents of the `tapply` function).

While this doesn't quite answer your question, hopefully you will find there are enough places you can break a line in R that the lack of the special command you are looking for isn't a problem.

Comment: That definitely suits my needs. In fact I tried something like that but put the <- in the following line so it didn't work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can just split commands on various lines, no special sign needed.

The command you wrote is almost OK, you just need to put the `<-` operator on the first line.

So for instance, this is valid R code, and will assign 13 to `a`

```
a <-
   5 +
   8
```

But this is not

```
a
  <- 5 +
  8
```

Note, however, that this is valid code

```
a <-
  5
  + 8
```

But would assign 5 to `a` and print 8.